# Keeping object in memory (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory, uiimageview

I am trying to create a UIImageView called *theImageView* in the touchesBegan method that I can then then move to a new location in touchesMoved. Currently I am receiving an "undeclared" error in touchesMoved where I set the new location for *theImageView*.

What can I do to keep *theImageView* in memory between these two methods?

**EDIT:** I am unable to declare *theImageView* in the @interface as I need to create an image every time a certain point is touched.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
    UIImageView *theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    theImageView.frame = CGRectMake(263, 228, 193, 300);
    [theImageView retain];
    ...
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
    theImageView.frame = CGRectMake(300, 300, 193, 300);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have declared the variable in a method/function, which makes it a local variable (that is, a variable which exists only inside that function). To make it available in other methods you have to declare it as instance variable in your class's @interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry but I meant to say that I am unable to do this because I am trying to create a new UIImageView object every time a predetermined area of the screen is touched. This means that I will need to create these objects dynamically and therefore I am unable to declare them in the @interface. Is there any other way of going about this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Chris: I don't see why you think you're unable to do this. You can reassign instance variables to point to new objects.

Comment: Or have an instance variable to hold an NSMutableArray in which you put UIImageViews.

Comment: @Chris: this *is* the right answer.  Try it and see.  All you need to do is declare the UIImageView in the interface, delete `UIImageView` from the first line of `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.  Then, when you are sure it works, add `[theImageView release]` above the alloc and delete the line that says `[theImageView retain]` and that will stop all the memory leaks.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to keep all of the image views, you'll need to put them in an array just before you release them.